# How can I run the SQL like "SELECT * from table where columnA = temp_table_result"?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a temp_table defined as:

```
with temp_table as (
  select id from table_A where name="john" limit 1
)
```

This table returns 1 row with just the id
I want to select all rows in table_B where the column col_1 is equal to the result of temp_table:

Both of the following fail for me:

```
select * from table_B where col_1 = temp_table
select * from table_B where col_1 = temp_table.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.*
FROM TABLE_B AS T
JOIN TEMP_TABLE AS A ON T.COL_1=A.ID
```

Comment: The trouble is your CTE is nondeterministic. If there are 2 or more rows with name = 'john' in `table_A` you can get different ids on each on different runs. That is unless column `name`  is defined as unique in which case the limit clause is redundant.

Comment: it is not issue in my code. Topic starter defines temp_table as he needs/wants